# Is it possible to access files beyond WEB-INF folder in dev mode of GAE (java.security.AccessControlException: access denied)?

Tags: google-app-engine, access-denied, file-access

Is it possible to access files beyond WEB-INF folder in Google App Engine's development server ? Maybe I can somehow force GAE dev server to do not block external connections/file access ?

I'm trying to create Java version of [gae-sqlite](http://gae-sqlite.googlecode.com). But I can't access external sql server (mysql or h2db) due to `access denied` exceptions.

Call stack:

```
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.io.FilePermission C:\work\test_projects\gae_test\out\artifacts\gae_test_war_exploded\database.lock.db write)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:374)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:546)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(DevAppServerFactory.java:252)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkWrite(SecurityManager.java:962)
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:882)
    at org.h2.store.fs.FilePathDisk.createFile(FilePathDisk.java:121)
    at org.h2.store.fs.FileUtils.createFile(FileUtils.java:59)
    at org.h2.store.FileLock.lockFile(FileLock.java:327)
    at org.h2.store.FileLock.lock(FileLock.java:128)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.open(Database.java:542)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.openDatabase(Database.java:222)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of GAE SDK 1.6.1 it's not possible. If you guys later find the way to do it please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

According to [GAE for Java Questions](http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/java.html#readfile):

> Why can't I read from this file?
>
> It is possible to read from a file which is uploaded as part of your
>   application provided that it is in the following locations:
>
> - war/WEB-INF
> - in a location matching the `<resource-files>` pattern in `appengine-web.xml` (which by default includes everything)
>
> If the file location is not the issue, the problem may be that the
>   method you are using to read from the file is not whitelisted. Your
>   application can use any IO classes that are useful for reading from
>   the file system, such as File, FileInputStream, FileReader, or
>   RandomAccessFile. For a full list of whitelisted classes, please see
>   the JRE Class White List. If you need to get file access to your own
>   resources (such as properties files), you could put these files inside
>   of jars and use Class or ClassLoader to load them.

So to *answer* your question, the only available place besides the `WEB-INF` directory to **read** files from is whatever you specified in the `<resource-files>` entry in `appengine-web.xml`.

Now one thing I noticed is that you're trying to **read** a DB file which should be okay if you're only considering it **read-only**.  You **cannot** write to any "local" files because (from the same link):

> Why can't I write to this file?
>
> Writing to local files is not supported in App Engine due to the
>   distributed nature of your application. Instead, data which must be
>   persisted should be stored in the distributed datastore. For more
>   information see the documentation on the runtime sandbox.

Comment: Yeah, I've read this FAQ of course. Is there workaround for this ? I wonder why gae-sqlite works then.