# GWT: You will not be able to access files from your working directory on the production

Tags: java, gwt

```
Your working directory, (C:\dev\projects\org\tatis\web\workspace\eclipse\lotto-shop) is not equal to your web application root
(C:\dev\projects\org\tatis\web\workspace\eclipse\lotto-shop\target\lottoShop-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT)
You will not be able to access files from your working directory on the production server.
```

I see the above warnings when I start gwt app using mvn gwt:run, I think that could have caused some security exceptions I'm getting and also log4j cannot access my log file.

The closest I get is [is-it-possible-to-access-files-beyond-web-inf-folder-in-dev-mode-of-gae-java-se](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8950163/is-it-possible-to-access-files-beyond-web-inf-folder-in-dev-mode-of-gae-java-se)

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Error seems clear.  You are trying to use a file that isn't under your webroot.  Either you have defined your webroot wrong, or you are using a path that starts with '../' for example.

Comment: What tag do I use to specify a new webRoot, I found `<webappDirectory>` thanks